# Android app crahses on device but not when connected to android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-logcat

I am having a strange issue which i can not seem to resolve, i run my application on android studio and it is fine, but when disconnected and run on device it crashes! no error is showing in the logcat because it does not crash when connected! it is when i select an item from the navigation draw it crashes. can anybody kindly help me with this? thank you

Comment: The first case is your app running on device or on emulator?

Comment: app is running on device

Comment: i am thinking it may be something to do with the transition on the navigation drawer, it is not very smooth

Comment: Connect device with adb command and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Just resolved it.
Error:
My app used to run successfully whenever I run it from Android Studio. But everytime, I run it otherwise, it crashed  displaying message, " has stopped".
I hope you had the same issue.
[the actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoO7P.jpg)

Once you close/exit the app, there is no information provided under "Run" tab, so use "Logcat" to identify it.
[logcat error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRONh.jpg)

Logcat will show you the error, when your device is connected to Android Studio, regardless of the fact that it was run from Android Studio or from device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mostly, this issue occurs because of NullPointerException, and it usually occurs unexpectedly.